# strtotime not working with TIME?

Tags: php

My mysql column has this datetime value, `2011-04-11 11:00:00` when I am applying strtotime then its returning date less than today,whereas it should be greater than today.

also when I am trying this `strtotime(date('d/m/Y h:i A'));` code, its returning wrong values. Is there any problem with giving TIME in strtotime?

Basically I want to do, is to compare my mysql column date with today's date, if its in future then show "Upcoming" else show nothing?

Please help and advise, what should I do?

**Edited** code

```
$_startdatetime = $rs['startdatetime'];
$_isUpcoming = false;
if(!empty($_startdatetime)){
    $TEMP_strtime = strtotime($_startdatetime);
    $TEMP_strtime_today = strtotime(date('d/m/Y h:i A'));
    if($TEMP_strtime_today < $TEMP_strtime){
        $_isUpcoming = true;
        $_startdatetime = date('l, d F, Y h:i A' ,$TEMP_strtime);
    }
}
```

And the value in `$rs['startdatetime']` is `2011-04-11 11:00:00`. And with this value I am getting following output.

```
$TEMP_strtime - 1302519600
$TEMP_strtime_today - 1314908160
$_startdatetime - 2011-04-11 11:00:00
```

`$_startdatetime` its value is not formatted as the upcoming condition is false, so returning as is mysql value.

Comment: Please show the actual code you are using. The example you give makes no real sense

Comment: I agree with Pekka.  I use `strtotime()` all the time on the datetime data from MySQL tables and have not had any problems.  One way to troubleshoot is print out the date string that you are sending to `strtotime()` to ensure you're trying to convert the formatted string that you think you are sending.

Comment: I have edited question and included my source code, hope that will help you guys to understand better. Thanks!

Comment: $TEMP_strtime_today = strtotime(date('d/m/Y h:i A')); Also known as time() ?

Comment: Why are you doing `strtotime(date('d/m/Y h:i A'))`?  Just do `time()`.

Comment: Can you show example values of `$_startdatetime` and the resulting `$TEMP_strtime`?

Comment: @Pekka: Added output values I am getting with my code

Comment: Your code works fine (after making `$TEMP_strtime_today = time();`) for me: http://codepad.org/aOm5dsM2

Comment: That works, but didn't get reason why it wasn't working with `strtotime(date('d/m/Y h:i A'));`, both seems similar, then why is this issue?

Comment: To clear things up, the problem here is that `d/m/Y` is an INVALID time format.  You should use a valid format, or just use `time()`.

Comment: Guys should I mark the Ish's answer as "Answer" or what should I do now, just confused?

Comment: Marked it as answer, as no other answer and it also contains all solution of this problem. THANKS ALL :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`d/m/Y h:i A` is irreversible (*with strtotime*) format, use standard [formats](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_date.asp)  or use `time()` as recommended by Joel & Rocket

**PROBLEM**

```
<?php
echo $today = date('d/m/Y h:i A');
echo '<br />';
echo $time = strtotime($today);
echo '<br />';
echo date('d/m/Y h:i A', $time);
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**SOLUTION**

```
<?php
$today = strtotime(date('m/d/Y h:i:s')); <- use appropriate format
// OR 
$today = time(); @credit to Joel & Rocket
```

Comment: What do you mean irreversible?

Comment: I mean strtotime can't parse `d/m/Y h:i A` this back to TIMESTAMP

Comment: PHP might just be getting confused as to which is the month and which is the year.

Comment: @Ish: Turns out you are correct.  `d-m-Y` is a valid format, and `m/d/Y` is a valid format, but `d/m/Y` isn't.

Comment: @Ish: What are you doing man, don't copy & paste others solution, give yours? And that's the same thing what I have in my question.. do you find any difference in your answer?

Comment: @Prashant: What are you taking about?

Comment: @Rocket, actually earlier, @Ish not updated his answer with SOLUTION, that's why I said that. Earlier that was the same code which I have in my question.