# strtotime converts ints to timestamps

Tags: php, strtotime

For a program I was working on, I am looping through data, and I needed to know if a certain piece of data was a date or not.

For simplicity, I made a function called `is_date`, it looked like this:

```
function is_date($date){
    return strtotime($date) !== FALSE;
}
```

This seemed to work, but for some reason, it returned `TRUE` for ints (which aren't dates).

For example:

```
is_date('bob') //FALSE
is_date('01/05/2009') //TRUE
is_date('March 16, 2010') //TRUE
is_date(165000) //TRUE
```

Why does `is_date(165000)` return TRUE?  How can `strtotime` convert 165000 to a timestamp?

As a fix, I changed my `is_date` function to this:

```
function is_date($date){
    return !is_numeric($date) && strtotime($date) !== FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually just figured this out.  `strtotime`, as a format, can accept [times without colons](http://us.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.time.php).

Therefore, `strtotime(165000)` is the same as `strtotime('16:50:00')`.

http://ideone.com/Z4hwQ

Comment: you could always check php.net too, `strtotime` makes assumptions on input, be careful sometimes it mis interprets days/months if you are not careful and if they come in different formats (01/10/2011 vs 10/01/2011 -- which is month / day?)

Comment: @Jakub: Please see the answer (and its comments) to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661961/strtotime-not-working-with-time

Comment: @Jakub: To `strtotime`, `d-m-Y` is a valid format, and `m/d/Y` is a valid format, but `d/m/Y` isn't.

Comment: why are you giving me references? I'm pointing that out to you!? lol

Comment: I was pointing it out to others are reading this.  Also, I was showing you that `strtotime` does not 'misinterpret' dates, it just assumes they are in a certain format.